# what is the meaning of underlying table in VIEW'S definition

Tags: sql, mysql, view

am not understand ,

what is the meaning of **underlying table** in VIEW definition ,

```
A view is created by joining one or more tables. When you update record(s) in a view, it updates the records in the underlying tables that make up the view.

So, yes, you can update the data in a view providing you have the proper privileges to the underlying tables.
```

Answer (score 1):

Think of a view as a stored query, which appears to the user as a regular table. In practical terms, there's very little difference between a view:

```
SELECT somefield, otherfield
FROM theview
```

and what's actually happening at the database level:

```
SELECT somefield, otherfield
FROM (
   SELECT lots, of, useless,fields, somefield, otherfield
   FROM underlying, tables
   JOIN ...
) AS theview
```

Views save you from having to write the sub-query each time, so they're a time saver in that regard. However, views have the downside that depending on the underlying query, you might not able to run UPDATE/DELETE queries against the view as you could if you were directly accessing the underlying tables.

Answer (score 0):

It means that the tables you select from or join against to generate the view. In this case, specifically the ones used in the fields list.